# Prototype causing trouble with jQuery $ selector?

Tags: jquery, selector, prototype, expressionengine

I'm trying to be able to edit data from an ExpressionEngine channel via inline editing. 
I've followed this tip:
http://www.3roadsmedia.com/blog/inline-editing-with-expressionengine-and-ajax/

Which I'm able to work on a blank page. But when jquery gets involved. I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'attachEvent'
```

I googled it a bit, and I believe it messes with the `$` selector.Because when I added this:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

It started working. But I have another error still,

```
 Uncaught TypeError:Object [object Object] has no method 'dispatchEvent'
```

Which is probably related to the selector error? Looks like there are some known issues using prototype and jquery.

This is the other script that uses prototype:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', init, false);


function init() {
    makeEditable("editTitle");
}

function makeEditable(id) {
    Event.observe(id, 'click', function(){edit($(id))}, false);
    Event.observe(id, 'mouseover', function(){showAsEditable($(id))}, false);
    Event.observe(id, 'mouseout', function(){showAsEditable($(id), true)}, false);
}


function showAsEditable(obj, clear) {
    if (!clear) {
        Element.addClassName(obj, 'editable');
    } else {
        Element.removeClassName(obj, 'editable');
    }
}


function edit(obj) {
    Element.hide(obj);

    var textbox ='<div class="edit-area" id="' + obj.id + '_editor"><textarea name="' + obj.id + '" id="' + obj.id + '_edit">' + obj.innerHTML + '</textarea>';

    var button = '<input type="button" value="SAVE" id="' + obj.id + '_save"/> OR <input type="button" value="CANCEL" id="' + obj.id + '_cancel"/></div>';

    new Insertion.After(obj, textbox+button);

    Event.observe(obj.id+'_save', 'click', function(){saveChanges(obj)}, false);
    Event.observe(obj.id+'_cancel', 'click', function(){cleanUp(obj)}, false);
}


function cleanUp(obj, keepEditable) {
    Element.remove(obj.id+'_editor');
    Element.show(obj);
    if (!keepEditable) showAsEditable(obj, true);
}


function saveChanges(obj) {
    var new_content = escape($F(obj.id+'_edit'));

    obj.innerHTML = "Savingâ€¦";
    cleanUp(obj, true);

    var success = function(t){editComplete(t, obj);}
    var failure = function(t){editFailed(t, obj);}

    var url = 'http://path-to-your-scripts-folder/edit.php';
    var pars = 'id=' + obj.id + '&content=' + new_content;
    var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(url, {method:'post',
    postBody:pars, onSuccess:success, onFailure:failure});
}


function editComplete(t, obj) {
    obj.innerHTML = t.responseText;
    showAsEditable(obj, true);
}


function editFailed(t, obj) {
    obj.innerHTML = 'Sorry, the update failed.';
    cleanUp(obj);
}
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Hmm, it came in the package with the latest version of Foundation. Looks like it's v1.8.2

Comment: Newest version of jquery (1.9) didn't do any difference

Comment: You're not activating noConflict properly. Use: "$.noConflict();", then "jQuery." for all your jQuery calls instead of "$".

Comment: I tried to just search for `$` in the prototype library and replace with `$p`, the same with the script that uses prototype. No more conflicts! Looks like it's working actually. I think it's better to do it this way, since I'm only using Prototype with Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Since I was only using Prototype for a specific Ajax task, I replaced the `$` selector with `$p` instead, using a simple find and replace in both `prototype.js` and `editinplace.js`.

Comment: Not a good solution if you ever need to upgrade either of these scripts.